# Access second sheets always invalid index

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to create a new excel sheet, but when I'm trying to access second sheet, it always throws invalid index exception.

It always shows the error at `xlWs3 = xlWb2.Worksheets.get_Item(2);`

```
xlApp2 = new Excel.Application();
xlWb2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Add();
xlWs2 = xlWb2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWs2.Name = "Format OR";
for (int j = 1; j < rowor; j++)
{
    xlWb2.Sheets[1].Activate();
    if (fulldataOR[j][23] != "RJCT")
    {
        createHeaderformatOR(xlWs2);
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 1] = fulldataOR[j][2];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 2] = fulldataOR[j][3];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 3] = fulldataOR[j][4];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 4] = fulldataOR[j][5];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 5] = fulldataOR[j][6];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 6] = fulldataOR[j][7];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 7] = fulldataOR[j][8];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 8] = fulldataOR[j][9];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 9] = fulldataOR[j][12];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 10] = fulldataOR[j][13];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 11] = fulldataOR[j][14];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 12] = fulldataOR[j][15];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 13] = fulldataOR[j][16];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 14] = fulldataOR[j][17];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 15] = fulldataOR[j][18];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 16] = fulldataOR[j][19];
        xlWs2.Cells[berhasilOr, 17] = fulldataOR[j][20];
        xlWs2.Columns.AutoFit();
        berhasilOr++;
    }
}

xlWs3 = xlWb2.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
xlWs3.Name = "PBK - USD";
for (int j = 1; j < rowusd; j++)
{
    xlWb2.Sheets[2].Activate();
    if (fulldataUSD[j][9] == "USD")
    {
        if (fulldataUSD[j][11] != "RJCT")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(fulldataUSD[j][1]);
            createHeaderPBKUSD2(xlWs3);
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 1] = fulldataUSD[j][4];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 2] = fulldataUSD[j][5];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 3] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 4] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 5] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 6] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 7] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 8] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 9] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 10] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 11] = fulldataUSD[j][3];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 12] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 13] = fulldataUSD[j][2];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 14] = fulldataUSD[j][9];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 15] = fulldataUSD[j][6];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 16] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 17] = fulldataUSD[j][7];
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 18] = "";
            xlWs3.Cells[berhasilusd, 19] = "";
            berhasilusd++;
            xlWs3.Columns.AutoFit();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Use `xlWb2.Worksheets.Count` to see if it's not empty or less than 2 then call `get_Item` method.

Comment: @MasLoo yes i realize that microsoft excel 2013 and 2010 has some difference where microsoft excel 2010 already give 3 sheets when you create new workbook and microsoft excel 2013 only give you 1 sheets when you create new workbook, so i add the sheets then i call get_Item method ..

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MasLoo's comments:

1. Check if there is another sheets in your new workbook with `xlWb.Sheets.Count`
2. if count == 1 , you should add a new sheets first with `xlWb.Sheets.Add(After: xlWb.Sheets[xlWb.Sheets.Count]);`
3. After that you called the  `xlWb.Worksheets.get_Item(2);`
4. Enjoy!

Thankyou MasLoo for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with index 0 first.

xlWs2 = xlWb2.Worksheets.get_Item(0);